# reshape vector and fill last missing positions with nan

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector and want to reshape it into a matrix, but the lenghts don't match. I want the remaining spots in the matrix to be filled with `nan`

```
import numpy
vec = np.arange(7, dtype=float)
mat = np.reshape(vec,(3,3))      # not working since vector too short
```

desired output:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  nan, nan]])
```

How can I achieve the array without manually extending the vector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define an empty `NaN` array and update using `vec`. This leverages the fact that [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) returns a view into the array, hence any modifications will be reflected in the actual array:

```
out = np.full((3,3), np.nan)
out.ravel()[:len(vec)] = vec

print(out)
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 6., nan, nan]])
```